# PHP file load twice in Chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, post

I'm having a problem when I try to insert mydata with my php file, then I check on Network tab, It's showing that my insertt.php running 2 times then it insert blank row to my database which I don't want here are my Codes.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" > 
<head>
  <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="icon128-2x.png">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input { 
    text-align: center;    
}
  </style>
</head>
  <body style="background-color:lightgreen;">
  <!--div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:lightblue;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
  <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
</div-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Thaishop Online</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#!/view1">หน้าหลัก <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/view2">วิธีการใช้งาน</a></li>
       <!-- <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>-->
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!/view2">สมัครสมาชิก</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!/viewLogin">เข้าสู่ระบบ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<img src="img\banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" >








  <div ng-view></div>




  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="viewLogin/viewLogin.js"></script>
  <script src="viewSaveCafeDetail/viewSaveCafeDetail.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

view2.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
            controller: 'FrmController'
        });
    }])

    .controller('FrmController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

        $scope.table = "";

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";
            $scope.Firstname = "";
            $scope.Lastname = "";
            $scope.Email = "";
            $scope.Tel = "";
            $scope.AccountStat = "";
            $scope.VerifyCode = "";
            $scope.Verifystat = "";
            $scope.cafe_id = "";
            $scope.CafeName = "";
            $scope.CafeUrl = "";
            $scope.ajouter = "";
        }
        $scope.auth = function () {
            $location.url('/view1');
        };


        $scope.path = 'http://localhost/middlework/administration/dash.php';

        $scope.deleteData = function (cafe_id) {
            alert('ddd');


            var path = $scope.path + '?n=' + $scope.table + '&id="' + cafe_id + '"&action=delete' + '&app=true';

            $http.get(path)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    $scope.getData();
                }, function (response) {
                    //Second function handles error
                    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
        }


        $scope.editData = function (id) {


            var path = $scope.path + '?n=' + $scope.table + '&id="' + id + '"&action=edit' + '&app=true';

            $http.get(path)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.id = response.data[0].id;
                    $scope.CafeName = response.data[0].CafeName;
                    $scope.update = true;


                }, function (response) {
                    //Second function handles error
                    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
        }

        $scope.getData = function () {



            var path = $scope.path + '?n=' + $scope.table + '&app=true';

            $http.get(path)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    $scope.content = response.data;
                    $scope.update = false;
                    $scope.reset();
                }, function (response) {
                    //Second function handles error
                    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
        }



        $scope.sendEmail = function () {


            $http.post('http://localhost/sendmail.php', $scope.formdata
            ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);


                }

            }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                $location.url('/view1');
                console.log(data);
            });

        }




        $scope.SignUp = function () {


            var Username = $scope.formdata.Username;
            var session_id = /SESS\w*ID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
            $scope.AccountStat = "USER";
            $scope.Verifystat = "Verified";
            $scope.table = "Users";
            $scope.ajouter = 1;
            $scope.formdata;
            var path = 'http://localhost/insertt.php';
            var Password = $scope.formdata.Password;
            var ConPass = $scope.formdata.ConfirmPassword;
            var Firstname = $scope.formdata.Firstname;
            var Lastname = $scope.formdata.Lastname;
            var Email = $scope.formdata.Email;
            var Tel = $scope.formdata.Tel;
            var CafeName = $scope.formdata.CafeName;
            var postdata = {

                'Username': $scope.formdata.Username,
                'Password': $scope.formdata.Password,
                'Firstname': $scope.formdata.Firstname,
                'Lastname': $scope.formdata.Lastname,
                'Email': $scope.formdata.Email,
                'Tel': $scope.formdata.Tel,
                'CafeName': $scope.formdata.CafeName,
                'AccountStat': $scope.AccountStat,
                'Verifystat': $scope.Verifystat,
                'ajouter': $scope.ajouter,
                'table': $scope.table,
                'app': true
            };
            var headers = {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
                "Content-Type": "undefined",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
            }
            if (Password == ConPass) {

                $http.post(path, postdata, headers
                ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                       // alert("สมัครสมาชิกสำเร็จ");
                       //  $location.url('/view1');
                        //$scope.insertcafe();
                        //$scope.sendEmail();
                        //  $scope.reset();
                        //  $scope.getData();


                    }

                }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.log(data);
                });

            } else {
                alert('กรุณากรอก Password ให้ตรงกัน');
            }

        }
        $scope.insertcafe = function () {
            var Username = $scope.formdata.Username;
            var CafeName = $scope.formdata.CafeName;
            $scope.table = "cafe";
            $scope.ajouter = 1;
            $scope.formdata;
            var path = $scope.path;
            var postdata = {

                'Username': $scope.formdata.Username,
                'CafeName': $scope.formdata.CafeName,
                'ajouter': $scope.ajouter,
                'table': $scope.table,
                'app': true
            };
            var headers = {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
            }
            $http.post(path, postdata, headers
            ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);




                }

            }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log("mai sum red");
            });


        }
    });
```

view2.html

```
 <div  >
    <form name="form1"  method="post" style="text-align:center;" align="center">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" >
        <label for="InputName" ><h1>กรอกข้อมูลผู้ใช้</h1></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.Firstname"  name="inputFirstname" placeholder="ชื่อจริง" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.Lastname" name="inputLastname" placeholder="นามสกุล" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.Username"  placeholder="Username" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.Password"  placeholder="Password" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.ConfirmPassword"  placeholder="Password อีกครั้ง" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="formdata.Email" name="inputEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.Tel" name="inputTel" placeholder="โทรศัพท์">
        </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.CafeName" name="inputCafeName" placeholder="ชื่อร้าน">
        </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="table" value="cafe">
          <input type="hidden" ng-model="ajouter" value="1" >
          <input ng-model="insertuser" ng-show="formdata.Firstname.length && formdata.Lastname.length && formdata.Username.length && formdata.Password.length &&
          formdata.ConfirmPassword.length && formdata.Email.length && formdata.Tel.length && formdata.CafeName.length" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit" value="insert" class="btn btn-primary">
       <!--<input ng-model="insertuser" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit" value="insertt" class="btn btn-primary">-->
        </div>
</form>



                        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="cafe_id" value="" placeholder="CafeId"></br>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="CafeName" value="" placeholder="CafeName"></br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="Username" value="" placeholder="Username"></br>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="CafeUrl" value="" placeholder="CafeUrl"></br>
                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="table" value="cafe">
          <input type="hidden" ng-model="ajouter" value="1" >
          <input ng-hide="update" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit" value="insert" class="btn btn-primary">
          <input ng-show="update" ng-click="update();" type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">

          <input ng-click="getData();" type="submit" value="get" class="btn btn-primary">-->

<table  border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in content">
  <td>{{x.id}}</td>
  <td>{{x.CafeName}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="editData(x.id)" >Edit</button></td>
  <td><button ng-click="deleteData(x.id)" >Del</button></td>
</tr>
</table>



    </form>
</div>
```

insertt.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER');
    header("Content-Type : application/json");/*or whatever type is relevant */
        header("Accept : application/json");

$serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "";
    $dbName = "middlework";

    $conn = new mysqli($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
session_start();

  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO users ";
$strSQL .="(Username,Password,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Tel,AccountStat,VerifyCode,Verifystat) ";
$strSQL .="VALUES ";
$strSQL .="('".$request->Username."','".$request->Password."','".$request->Firstname."' ";
$strSQL .=",'".$request->Lastname."','".$request->Email."','".$request->Tel."','User','".session_id()."','None') ";


#$findmax = "SELECT MAX(cafe_id)  FROM cafe where Username = 'kkk'";

#$max = $conn->query($findmax);
#$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max);
#while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max)) {
   # echo $row['cafe_id'];

#}
mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL);
/*if(mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL))
{
    echo "Save User Done.[".$strSQL."]";

}
else
{
    echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]";
}*/
    $insertcafe = "INSERT INTO cafe (cafe_id,Username,CafeName) VALUES ('1' , '".$request->Username."', '".$request->CafeName."')";
if($conn->query($insertcafe))
{
    echo "Save Cafe Done.[".$insertcafe."]";
}
else
{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "Save Cafe Fail[".$insertcafe."]";
}
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "kitsakorn.p55@rsu.ac.th"; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = "1100501068349"; // GMAIL password
$mail->From = "kitsakorn.p55@rsu.ac.th"; // "name@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "ThaiCoffeeShopOnline";  // set from Name
$mail->Subject = "ยืนยันการสมัครสมาชิก ThaiCoffeeShopOnline";                            
$mail->Body = "ขอขอบคุณที่สมัครเป็นสมาชิกกับเรา กรุณาคลิก Url ด้านล่างเพื่อทำการ Activate บัญชีของคุณ</br>
               http://localhost/activate.php?sid=".session_id()."&uid=".$request->Username."</br></br> ThaiCoffeeShop.com";




$mail->AddAddress($request->Email); // to Address

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    //json_decode();
}
/*for ($i=1;$i<100;$i++){
    $insertcafe = "INSERT INTO cafe (cafe_id,Username,CafeName) VALUES ('".$i."' , 'kkk', '".$request->CafeName."')";
#$queryy = $conn->query($insertcafe);
if($conn->query($insertcafe))
{
    echo "Save Cafe Done.[".$insertcafe."]";

    break;
}
else
{

    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "Save Cafe Fail.".$i."[".$insertcafe."]";
}
echo $request->CafeName;
}*/
$conn->close();
?>
```

app.js

```
    'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.viewLogin',
  'myApp.SaveCafeDetail',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.